# Python basemap mismatch with scatter lat/long

Tags: python, geospatial, spatial, matplotlib-basemap

Hi I have a dataframe (Df) with lat/long and values

```
lat lon utci
0   90.0    -180.00 242.923935
1   90.0    -179.75 242.923935
2   90.0    -179.50 242.923935
3   90.0    -179.25 242.923935
4   90.0    -179.00 242.923935
```

And I'm trying to overlap the scatterplot of that with Basemap as below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, addcyclic, shiftgrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlat=-60, urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=179.75, resolution='c')
m.bluemarble(scale=0.2)   # full scale will be overkill
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()
x, y = m(Df.lon.values, Df.lat.values)  # transform coordinates

plt.scatter(x,y, s=Df.utci,c=Df.utci-273,cmap='coolwarm')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

It works ok but there is a mismatch between my data's boundaries and the basemap coastlines. Any idea what parameter I need to adjust to fix this?
Thanks in advance

[image: Final map with mismatch country borders]

Comment: Try `Basemap(projection='cyl',...)`.

Comment: This projection didn't help, unfortunately :/